# If $P(G)>0$, then $\int_GX\ dP<0$ where $G:=\{X<0\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. Let $G:=\{X<0\}$. If $P(G)>0$, then $\int_GX\ dP<0$.

I came up with this exercise in measure theory when I tried to recover the proof of a property of conditional expectations: if $X\leq Y$ a.s., then
$
E(X|\Sigma)\leq E(Y|\Sigma)
$
a.s.

One can get immediately "$\int_G X\leq 0 $" by the property of integral. But I don't see how to get rid of the equal sign.

I'm quite sure that I have seen similar questions here before but I can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: One of the sets $\{X < -1/n\}, n = 1,2,\dots $ has positive measure.